# Fixing navbar element wrapping in materializecss navbar

Tags: html, css, materialize

My navbar looks like this:

```
<div class="navbar-fixed" id="navigation">
    <ul id="alert_type_nav_drop_down" class="dropdown-content">
    </ul>

    <nav>
        <div class='nav-wrapper'>
            <ul id='nav-mobile' class='left'>
            <li><a href='/'><img src='http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/gtawiki/images/9/9a/PlayStation_1_Logo.png/revision/latest?cb=20100130082645' height='25px'></a></li>
              <li><a href='/'>Test</a></li>
              <li><a href='/'>Another Test</a></li>
              <li><a href='/'>Heyyy</a></li>
              <li><a href='/'>Whyyy</a></li>
              <li><a href='/'>Okkkkkk</a></li>
              <li><a href='/'>Los Angeles</a></li>
            </ul>
            <a class="right black-text valign-wrapper"><img class="circle responsive-img" width=50px
                                                                           src="http://www.stockvault.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Portrait-8.jpg"></a>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

fiddle: https://fiddle.jshell.net/g3mvhvdk/

The problem is that when the window size is too small, elements wrap around into the body of the page like so:

[image]

When it normally looks like this:

[image]

What's a good way to fix this problem? Should I make the elements horizontally scrollable?

As per suggestions in the comment, I've added the following:

```
<div class="navbar-fixed hide-on-med-and-down" id="navigation">
```

which will hide my nav bar when it resizes to be something small enough, my question is, how do I show the hamburger if the navbar's hidden? Is there a helper "show-on-med-and-down" class? I suppose the bigger question is, is there an elegant way to switch from showing a navbar to showing a hamburger and a sidebar?

Comment: Would you consider hiding the menu items on smaller screen sizes, and instead showing a 'menu' or 'hamburger icon' that shows the items when clicked?

Comment: So turn this into a sidenav when it's too small?

Comment: it's an option. At smaller size screens people are familiar with drop down menus. Alternatively, just set the nav height to a percentage instead of using pixels, and change the value as necessary using media queries

Comment: Will update the question with a small problem that I'm finding

Answer (score -1):

```css
.nav-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#nav-mobile {
  flex: 100;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately while this fixes the image from wrapping around, the elements get shifted so that they're not visible

Comment: @Stupid.Fat.Cat At the fair you don't need in this thread to ask to ask advice on design. The design should be developed. But if you have problems with the implementation of the finished design, here are willing to help. Show a picture of how you want this to work on small resolutions.